# Can ColdFusion send HTML5 Server-Sent Events in utf-8?

Tags: html, google-chrome, coldfusion, server-sent-events

using `<cfcontent type="text/event-stream">` in ColdFusion, the non-English characters are displayed as question marks: `???????123123???? ???`, but the rest of the page can display non-English characters just fine.

I followed [this tutuorial](http://www.html5rocks.com/tutorials/eventsource/basics/) and tried

`<cfheader name="Content-Type" value="text/event-stream; charset=utf-8">`

and also

`<cfcontent type="text/event-stream; charset=utf-8">`

Both of them do not work with Chrome (doesn't pick up, developer tool reported "pending" with no reconnection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tried the following code and it's working fine (showing the correct characters in Chrome's console)...

**testHTML5ServerSent events**

```
    <HTML>

    <HEAD>
        <script language="javascript">
        if (!!window.EventSource) {
            var source = new EventSource('sendServerSentEvents.cfm');           
            source.addEventListener('message', function(e) { 
                                                    console.log(e.data);
                                                }, false);

source.addEventListener('open', function(e) {
  // Connection was opened.
}, false);

source.addEventListener('error', function(e) {
  if (e.eventPhase == EventSource.CLOSED) {
    // Connection was closed.
  }
}, false);

        } else {
            alert('not supported');// Result to xhr polling :(
        }


        </script>
    </HEAD>

    <BODY>

    </BODY>

</HTML>
```

sendServerSentEvents.cfm

```
    <cfcontent type="text/event-stream; charset=utf-8" >
data: éêtititiçà
</cfcontent>
```